# How does sequent validity differ from semantic entailment?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I am busy with some logic exercises and I am getting a bit stuck with a certain question. Now, I am not expecting to simply get the answer as I know that won't help me, but I just need a nudge in the right direction.

This is the sequent I am looking at:

$$
p\to(q\lor r)\vdash (p\to q)\land(p\to r)
$$

I need to state whether the sequent is valid or not. What I did to try to prove this, is to draw the truth table for all sentences, and see if I can find any case where the first sentence is T, but the second sentence is F. I did find 2 cases for this (p = T, q = T, r = F **and** p = T, q = F, r = T). This is what I used to prove that the sequent is invalid.

However, upon further inspection, I realised that what I did was to actually prove that the second sentence is not **semantically entailed** by the first sentence, which I believe is not the same thing as proving **validity of a sequent**.

Therefore, my question is: can you prove sequent validity by proving semantic entailment? My understanding of semantic entailment is that **for all combinations of premises being T, the conclusions must also be T.** But that is not what the question is asking for specifically.

Please help!

**EDIT:**

This is a multiple choice question, and these are the options:

1. The sequent is valid and can be formally proved using natural deduction rules.
2. The sequent is valid as shown by the following valuation: p = F, q = F, r = T
3. The sequent is not valid as shown by the following valuation: p = F, q = F, r = F
4. The sequent is not valid as shown by the following valuation: p = T, q = F, r = T

My answer is 4, but that is what I am questioning. Option 2 also seems correct, and that is why I am confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Completeness and deduction theorem would do it for you, but I suppose you want a direct approach?

Comment: Thanks user10354138 - I have edited my question to provide more clarity

Comment: Not valid......